# TeX Studio - Keyboard shortcuts

Tags: texstudio, shortcut

Is there any keyboard shortcut to move from the left editor pane to the right pdf viewer pane? (Windows or Ubuntu).

[image: Panes]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could look into the options.

[image: options]

Within the option dialog it is also possible to change the shortcuts for that.